# Unable to create table in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Following is my query to create table,

```
String CREATE_OWNER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_OWNER + "(" + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_SUM + "TEXT NOT NULL  );";
db.execSQL(CREATE_OWNER_TABLE);
```

I wrote a query like that to create table owner. But there is an error that shows me that the table does not have a column called sum

Comment: post logcat .........

Comment: Please post your error with some more code.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a space before your last column's data type declaration

```
KEY_SUM + "TEXT NOT NULL
```

Add a space like below,

```
String CREATE_OWNER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_OWNER + "(" + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_SUM + " TEXT NOT NULL  );";
db.execSQL(CREATE_OWNER_TABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 String CREATE_OWNER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_OWNER + "(" + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_CODE + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_SUM + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```